# UIAlertViewController not responds after slow animation on in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-simulator, xcode7

I am using xcode 7.2 today i notice very strange behavior in simulator. whenever i am opening `UIAlertViewController` with `ActionSheet` or `default` type with `Simulator slow-motion animations on` ( `⌘ + T` ) mode on simulator then after app not responding some time i can not able to do user Activity for few second (around 20 second). what is the issue of this i am using Swift for reference you can create demo using following code for `UIAlertViewController`

```
@IBAction func alertShow(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try allocating UIAlertController earlier let say in viewdidload, use that object in your IBAction function, Works fine with me